# Intersections of subgroups of surface groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, gr.group-theory

Let $\mathcal{S}_g$ denote the fundamental group of an oriented surface of genus $g\ge 2$.

Does $\mathcal{S}_g$ contain subgroups $A$ and $B$ of finite index such that $A\cap B = \lbrace e\rbrace$?

Comment: Intersection of two finite index subgroups is again a finite index subgroup, so the conclusion holds for all infinite groups. 

Comment: @Misha: Don't you mean the conclusion *doesn't hold*, since otherwise $|S_g|=(S_g:1)=(S_g:A\cap B))< \infty$ ? 

Comment: Ralph, yes, that's what I meant. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Misha says in a comment, for any group $G$ with subgroups $A,B$, we have

$|G:A\cap B|\leq |G:A||G:B|$

(exercise).  In particular, if $G$ is infinite (as here) then $A\cap B$ is non-trivial.